# How to reproduce a plot with fitted value graph and lowess smooth graph superimpose?

Tags: regression, logistic, data-visualization

I have a binary response variable (y) and continuous explanatory variable (age).
I utilised logistic regression to analyse them. I have a plot of y against age. What I want to do now is superimpose the fitted value plot and lowess plot on it.
So how do I do that?

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
plot(y~age)  
GLM <- glm(y~age, family=binomial)  
curve(plogis(-7.502+0.077*x), min(age), max(age), add=T, lwd=2, col="blue", type="l")  
lines(lowess(age, GLM$fitted, f=0.9), col="green")
```

Is this right/ the best way?

Comment: I've voted that this is off-topic. It appears to simply ask about how to replicate some R code. It would easier to answer the question if you provided a fully reproducible example and explain why the current code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the visreg package it is able to draw your plot very easily and it doesn't require a lot of coding either. First load the visreg package:

```
require('visreg')
```

Then create your model:

```
model <- glm(y~age, family="binomial")
```

And final plot your model, it will show your curve including the confidence interval.

```
visreg(model,scale="response",partial=FALSE,xlab="Age",ylab="P(y)", line=list(col="black"), ylim=c(0,1))
```

If you also want to add your points, just run the following:

```
points(y~age,pch=21,col="black", bg="red", cex=1)
```

It will look something like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I've check it against the code I used, and it gives me the same curve.